# npm mkdirp or make-dir not working in windows

Tags: windows, npm, copy, mkdir

I am new to npm and have created my first package.json file. I have tried different packages but cannot get npm to create a new directory and copy files into it.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "thera_home",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "move_css_dist": "make-dir dist/css && copyfiles ./WebContent/css/* dist/css"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.7.2"
  }
}
```

When I run npm -

```
npm run --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\tools\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\tools\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.12.1
npm info using node@v12.13.1
Scripts available in thera_home via `npm run-script`:
  move_css_dist
    make-dir dist/css && copyfiles ./WebContent/css/* dist/css
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 216ms
npm info ok
```

but dist/css directory does not get created. I manually created dist but the copyfiles does not copy files either. I have tried mkdir, mkdirp, and make-dir without any success.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your log indicates that the command you run was `npm run --verbose`. Have you actually tried telling npm which script to run, i.e. have you tried running the following command instead: `npm run move_css_dist` ?

Comment: Thanks RobC, running the command definitely helped in finding the actual error. I *thought* that I had installed copyfiles but must have slipped my mind. I also was able to remove the make-dir as copyfile creates a directory, if it doesn't exist.